# sqlite returns null when using where

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm going crazy about this. My query works if I don't use 'where', but the moment I insert 'where', it returns nothing. I'm dead sure the value specified in 'where' does exist.

here's my code that successfully returns the values:

```
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EVENTS, new String[] {"eventName, accountType"}, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Log.v(FILE_NAME, "eventName: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("eventName")));
            Log.v(FILE_NAME, "accountType: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("accountType")));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

here's the returned values:

```
01-16 18:42:39.979 V/DbHelper.java﹕ 
V/DbHelper.java﹕eventName: Evenesis Gathering
V/DbHelper.java﹕accountType: 1
V/DbHelper.java﹕eventName: Asia Conference
V/DbHelper.java﹕accountType: 1
```

but when I add the where value:

```
Cursor cursor;
        cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EVENTS, new String[] {"eventName, accountType"}, "accountType='1'", null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Log.v(FILE_NAME, "eventName: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("eventName")));
                Log.v(FILE_NAME, "accountType: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("accountType")));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

I got nothing. Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst) - on a side note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps accountType is an integer? If so, ditch the quotes:

```
cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EVENTS,
        new String[] {"eventName, accountType"}, "accountType=1",
        null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: i thought sqlite data types are 'loosely defined'? means although we set a particular column as integer, we could actually insert string inside the column too right? so why here suddenly sqlite being very strict?